# Assert creating a dialog in MFC app, Visual Studio 2015, dlgcore.cpp

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

I have converted an MFC app from Visual Studio 2010 to VS2015, running on Windows 7, 64-bit app.  Started getting the following error when trying to open dialogs:

```
title: Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\Windows\System32\mfc140d.dll
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgcore.cpp, Line: 210
```

My code causing the assert:

```
m_PropDlg = new xxxDlg( i, (CWnd*)this );  //xxxDlg inherits from CDialog
m_PropDlg->Create( IDD_PROP_DIALOG, NULL );  //CRASH HERE
```

dlgcore.cpp:

```
if( !_AfxCheckDialogTemplate( lpszTemplateName, FALSE ) )
{
   ASSERT(FALSE);  //invalid dialog template name
   PostNcDestroy();
   return FALSE;
}
```

This is a Dynamic Library (.dll), Use of MFC = "Use MFC in a Shared DLL".  I have tried putting the following before the Create call, but no change:

```
HINSTANCE hinst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
AfxSetResourceHandle(hinst);
```

Any help appreciated.
Ron

Comment: Have you verified, that the dialog template resource is indeed compiled into the binary, and that you are passing the correct name/ID? You can open the binary in Visual Studio and use its Resource Viewer to verify this.

Comment: @IInspectable.  Thanks.  By the "binary", do you mean the dll or what?

Comment: @IInspectable.  I opened the dll in VS and it shows a dialog with ID=3999, which is indeed the value of IDD_PROPERTIES_DIALOG if I debug the code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know, where things go wrong, but I need you to provide two more pieces of information: `1` Does `AfxGetInstanceHandle` return the base address of your DLL? Use Visual Studio's *Modules* window to find your DLL's base address. `2` Could you single-step through `_AfxCheckDialogTemplate` just before the assertion fails to determine, why it returns `FALSE`?

Comment: @IInspectable. Breakpoints don't hit in dlgcore.cpp.  I assume it is built into mfc140d.dll.  I'll have to figure out if I can step thru dlgcore.cpp.

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint on the `m_PropDlg->Create( IDD_PROP_DIALOG, NULL );`-statement, and then *step into*, if setting a breakpoint in dlgcore.cpp won't work for you. Maybe you should also double-check, that you are linking against the correct MFC binary, since this is a migrated project. Make sure there is no `mfc100.dll` (or variant) loaded into your process from the original VS2010 project.

Comment: @IInspectable.  I am just not coming up with anything.  Can't step into Create.  First I get the assert again, then if I try to step I get a window that says mfc140d.amd64.pdb not loaded...I don't have this file anywhere.  There is an include path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1..." but it won't compile without this because it doesn't find winsdkver.h.  Seems to correctly include "Windows Kits\10..." for the CRT.  It does sound like a mismatch between versions of something.

Comment: `new xxxDlg( i, (CWnd*)this );` the cast to `CWnd*` looks suspicious. Try `new xxxDlg(i, this);` or `new xxxDlg(i);` but don't force a `CWnd*` cast

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, Our xxxDlg function takes a CWnd*.  It worked fine in VS2010.  Just became a problem converting to VS2015.

Comment: If `this` is derived from `CWnd` then you shouldn't need a cast.

Comment: @BasicPoke: You need to set up your IDE to [use the Microsoft Symbol Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588.aspx#using_the_microsoft_symbol_server).